# Cannot assing shortcut which contain Alt + shift in IntelliJ

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-18.04

I have the following problem: on my Ubuntu 18.04 I assigned `Alt + Shift` to change the language, but now when I want to assign `Alt + Shift + I` for a shortcut for `Generate` in IntelliJ. When I try to assign it I press Alt + Shift + I and nothing happens and when I release them the language is changed and the shortcut is not assigned. So is there a way to intercept the OS shortcuts when the IntelliJ is in focus? 
Moreover `Alt + Shift + R` is assigned for rename, but It is not working. When I press `Alt + Shift + R` nothing happens and when I release them the language is changed. 
So is there any fix for this?
I am talking about shortcuts in Java classes(I do not try them in js and so on).

P.S. I hit the same problem with Eclipse. So it is something related to the OS. Unfortunately I have no idea why that's happening. :(
Thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: What JDK do you use to run IDE ("Help | About")?

Comment: It shows me `JRE: 1.8.0_152 etc`

Comment: Actually I have the same problem with Eclipse! So it is something from the OS. Does someone have an idea what's going in?

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows. Intellij has some default shortcuts that use Alt+Shift+somethingelse but if you want to add more, or replace them, you just can't use Alt+Shift in the shortcut editor. I'm gonna try to see if I can manually modify these from the intellij config files, and then if they will work at all in the first place.

Comment: Nope, it still doesn't work even if I manually set the shortcut by modifying the configuration file. Man I wish column editing mode would work like in Notepad++, it's so handy over there.